# Firebase/NoSQL Database Structure

Tags: json, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am trying to structure a nosql database for the first time. I have a user table which contains: name and email address. Now each user can have more than 1 device.

Each device has multiple basically has an array of readings.

Here is what my current structure looks like:

[image]

How can i improve this structure?

ps: I am using angularjs with angularfire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In relational databases, there is the concept of normal forms and thus related a somewhat objective measure of whether a data model is normalized.

In NoSQL databases you often end up modeling the data for the way your app consumes it. Hence there is little concept of what constitutes a good data model, without also considering the use-cases of your app.

That said: the [Firebase documentation recommends flattening your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure). More specifically it recommends against mixing types of data, like you are doing with user metadata and device metadata.

The recommendation would be to split them into two top-level nodes:

```
/users
  <userid1>
   email:
   id:
   name:
  <userid2>
   email:
   id:
   name:
/devices
  <userid>
    <deviceid1>
      <measurement1>
      <measurement2>
    <deviceid2>
      <measurement1>
      <measurement2>
```

Further recommended reading is [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing our [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). Oh and of course, the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).

Comment: Hey @ Frank van Puffelen, thank you very much for your reply. So under devices i would put the device id as well correct?

Comment: Yup. I overlooked that in your JSON, so updated my answer with the extra layer. Btw, for a next question: post the JSON as text please (you can easily export it from the Firebase Console). That allows me to re-use it in the answer (amongst many other benefits).

Comment: I would like to query the database for the last device that a currently signed in user used, how can I do that?

Do i have to query first the users and then check it with the devices?